# Echoing a div in PHP, renewed

Tags: php, html, css

So, my php looks like this:

```
function gs_home_widgets() {

        genesis_widget_area(
                'home-top', 
                array(
                        'before' => '<aside id="home-top" class="home-top home-widget widget-area">', 
                        'after' => '</aside><!-- end #home-top -->',
                ) 
        );

        genesis_widget_area( 
                'home-cta', 
                array(
                        'before' => '<aside id="home-cta" class="home-cta"><div class="home-widget widget-area">', 
                        'after' => '</div></aside><!-- end #home-left -->',
                ) 
        );

        echo '<div id="home-divider" class="home-divider">';

        genesis_widget_area( 
                'home-divider-left', 
                array(
                        'before' => '<aside id="home-divider-left" class="home-divider-left first one-half"><div class="home-widget widget-area">', 
                        'after' => '</div></aside><!-- end #home-divider-left -->',
                ) 
        );

        genesis_widget_area( 
                'home-divider-right', 
                array(
                        'before' => '<aside id="home-divider-right" class="home-divider-right one-half"><div class="home-widget widget-area">', 
                        'after' => '</div></aside><!-- end #home-divider-right -->',
                ) 
        );

        echo '</div>';                        
}

genesis();
```

I'm trying to style the "home-divider" div with a "background-color: #E96151;" so that "home-divider-left" and "home-divider-right" will be colored correctly, but, well.... here's what it looks like:

[image: Click here for the image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"renewed"_?

Comment: I've seen some other posts on here that relate, but none with this specific problem.

Comment: This does not seem related to php, you should post the html and css.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: So what's that have to do with putting _"renewed"_ in the title?  Just post a good descriptive title.

Comment: Although the question is not said, my problem is still explained. And please don't criticize my specificity, I explained and elaborated as best I could. For Jeroen: I gave you as much HTML, CSS, and PHP as is in front of me

Comment: Don't get defensive.  This place remains a high quality repository because people take the time to politely moderate other users.  You may disagree but your question needs some work:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How would you title this problem so I can re-title it and get my question answered?

Comment: **Quote OP**:  _"How would you title this problem so I can re-title it and get my question answered?"_  ~ Again, read this page ->>>:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you espnicholas that solved it for me.

Comment: Sorry I put it in answers if you could vote for it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't really completely explain your problem. For all I can really tell the reason a background color might not be showing is because you left and right columns are floating objects and your wrapper, "home-divider" isn't being cleared so it doesn't detect the height. That's all I can really guess from what you're asking. Look into the clear fix solution.

Comment: Right on the money. Thank you.